# Native iOS list of buttons with arrow to the right

Tags: ios, react-native

I have used React with MUI and starting to explore React Native. I have read the documentation but can not seem to find this basic example.

How do I create a list of buttons(button group) with icons to the right?

I would like to do something similar to MUI like `<Button endIcon={<ArrowRight />} />`
but achieve the Native iOS look and feel.

Like the Settings app on iOS:

```
| General —-——————————————- —> |

| Control Center —————————- —> |

| Display & Brightness ———— —> |
```

Is there a way to do this without coding the entire thing from scratch?

[image: iOS Settings app]

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a third party package for this somwhere, but my advice would be to use SectionList from react-native and RectButton from react-native-gesture-handler to get the native ios/android feel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FlatList with custom buttons and apply styles to it.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

Example of button content:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <View style={{flex: 0.3}}>Icon here</View>
    <View style={{flex: 0.5}}><Text>Text here</Text></View>
    <View style={{flex: 0.2, alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>Icon here</View>
</View>
```